# Visual Studio crashes when opening project in designer view

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crash

I've recently started making a website in ASP.NET, but I can barely progress because of Visual Studio crashing when opening the design view.

At first, I used Visual Studio 2012, and it started crashing. Now, I've installed 
Visual Studio 2015 (still a preview) because I needed to use a newer version anyway, and this was the opportunity to try if it crashed in 2015 too.

I've tried resetting the settings with the Tools>Import and Export settings.

I've also seen that people were having this problem from the UserControl, but 
I do not use that.

I don't have a clue what is going on. 

I only have this crash when opening a certain design view of a certain page.

Now my question is, do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Share the screenshot of the error it spits out before crashing. And one more thing: VS 2015 is not stable at all (especially its most recent release)

Comment: @TalhaIrfan It does not show any errors. And I'm aware of 2015 not being stable.

Comment: Is VS 2010 working for other Project types in C#?

Comment: Have you tried to open any prebuilt ASP.Net code in your VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact problem, but apparently my gridView have made my Visual Studio crash.
 I removed it and recoded it, and it works fine! So I recommend to take a look at your gridView...